# "Now is the time to" or "Now is time to" – Which is correct?

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns, sentence-starts

Which of the following two phrases is correct?

> Now is the time to
>   Now is time to

Or are both of them correct? And if so is "Now is the time to" more formal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now is the time to

is correct.

---

Compare it to something like this:

> Tomorrow is the day to

or

> Tomorrow is day to

---

Although, you could edit the second option to:

> Now **it** is time to